# osgi r6 service.component.annotations property list

Tags: java, osgi

How do I set a list in a property value?
For example with the `felix scr` annotations, a Servlet looked somewhat like this:

```
@Component(metatype = false)
@SlingServlet(
 methods = { "GET", "POST" },
 resourceTypes = "sling/servlet/default",
 selectors = { "size" },
 paths = { "/some/stupid/path/.*" }
```

with the new osgi service annotations

```
@Component(service = Servlet.class,
    property = { 
     "sling.servlet.methods=GET",
     "sling.servlet.methods=POST",
     "sling.servlet.resourceTypes=sling/servlet/default",
     "sling.servlet.selectors=size",
     "sling.servlet.paths=/some/stupid/path.*" })
```

How can I set the `servlet.methods` as a list? Admittedly in this example it is not much of a problem, but I have a Servlet that activates on a lot of selectors, and I really do not want to have 20 lines of `sling.servlet.selectors=...`

Comment: I tried it out by looking at the generated OSGI-INF metadata xml. it seems that specifying it via `[GET,POST]` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

From the javadoc: `To specify a property with multiple values, use multiple name, value pairs. For example, "foo=bar", "foo=baz".` So what you have should work in that the value of `sling.servlet.methods` will be an array `[GET,POST]`

Support for the future DS 1.4 spec should make this easier by allowing annotations to set property values. See 5.10 in [RFC 222](https://github.com/osgi/design/tree/master/rfcs/rfc0222).