# Handling events using ResourceChangeListener AEM 6.3

Tags: annotations, osgi, aem, addeventlistener

Can someone please help me in understanding how to implement a ResourceChangeListener and handle events using osgi R6 annotations?
I saw a similar post with no answer.[AEM 6.3 - Creating Event handler using OSGi R6 annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46938213/aem-6-3-creating-event-handler-using-osgi-r6-annotations)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The code snippet below registers a ResourceChangeListener with OSGI R6 annotations. The comments inline have the explanation.

```
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.observation.ResourceChange;
import org.apache.sling.api.resource.observation.ResourceChangeListener;
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

@Component(
    service = ResourceChangeListener.class,
    property = {
        // filter the notifications by path in the repo. Can be array and supports globs
        ResourceChangeListener.PATHS+"="+"/content",
        //The type of change you want to listen to.
        //Possible values at https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling9/org/apache/sling/api/resource/observation/ResourceChange.ChangeType.html.
        ResourceChangeListener.CHANGES+"="+"ADDED",
        ResourceChangeListener.CHANGES+"="+"REMOVED",
        ResourceChangeListener.CHANGES+"="+"CHANGED"

        //PS: If you want to declare multiple values for a prop, you repeat it in OSGI R6 annotations.
        //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41243873/osgi-r6-service-component-annotations-property-list#answer-41248826
    }
)
public class SampleResourceChangeListener implements ResourceChangeListener{ // Use ExternalResourceChangeListener to listen for changes that happen in a different node
  public static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SampleResourceChangeListener.class);

  //This method will be called with paths and types of change that occurred
  //The task in this should be fast. In case it takes more time, trigger a sling job from here.
  //The listener can be blacklisted if it's slow [it does for event handler, should be same for ResourceListener IMHO]
  @Override
  public void onChange(List<ResourceChange> list) {
    list.forEach((change) -> {
      LOGGER.info(change.getPath());
      LOGGER.info(change.getType().toString());
      //the methods to identify the property that changed are deprecated.
    });
  }
}
```

Some reference implementations within Sling

1. https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-discovery-commons/blob/4f7d7ca3224239d52798cc8418ec8283f5eddc9e/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/discovery/commons/providers/spi/base/IdMapService.java
2. https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-scripting-java/blob/89c28859a7df17a40eaaf2c26ee2433c98830204/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/scripting/java/impl/JavaScriptEngineFactory.java

Comment: Thanks a lot for this. Now on adding a node my Listener is getting invoked. Since my path is pointing to a DAM asset path, this listener is getting invoked for all the subnodes as well like jcr:content, renditions (each one separately). How do I restrcit it for just the parent node and not the child nodes. ?

Comment: you only want it to be fired on the node type dam:Asset or the original rendition ?

Comment: yes..I am trying the same thing..and it is working..thanks once again for your replies.

Comment: If i need to make the ResourceChangeListener.PATHS+"="+"/content", alone configurable, what changes do i need to make here? I created this :         @ObjectClassDefinition(name="test Listener")
    public @interface TsetConfiguration {
       
        @AttributeDefinition(
            name = "Resource Path",
            description = "Resource path where the file is present",
            type = AttributeType.STRING
        )
        String getResourcepath() default "/content";
    }but then how do use it as ResourcePath property?

Comment: I guess you have register the resource change listener dynamically in the activate method. Check out configureCache method in https://github.com/apache/sling-org-apache-sling-scripting-core/blob/b68a89f46629c6d661d65ec9f0fc9067cccc24fe/src/main/java/org/apache/sling/scripting/core/impl/ScriptCacheImpl.java . Be sure to unregister and existing listener before you register with new props

Comment: This works under 6.3? I see null for addedPropertyNames, changedPropertyNames, etc. when I debug through this.